# Autofill sporadically failing after build, and not working (Swift)

Tags: swift, drawing

I've been out of the game for way too long. Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Here's the YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YcDBMMjj0wU&t=199s) I was watching, for reference.

[Check errors here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30qeu.png)

Here's the code:

```
import UIKit

class DrawExamples: UIView {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // context is the object used for drawing
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0)
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.purpleColor().CGColor)

        /*
        //straight line
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 30, 30)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 150, 320)
        */

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 50, 50)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 90, 130)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 180, 100)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 90, 60)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 90, 130)


        //Actually draw the path
        CGContextStrokePath(context)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method signature has changed, in Swift 5 you can use this code:

```
class DrawExamples: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            context.setLineWidth(3.0)
            context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.purple.cgColor)

            context.move(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 90, y: 130))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 180, y: 100))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 90, y: 60))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 90, y: 130))
            context.strokePath()
        }
    }
}
```

Аfter you have configured the view in custom class, you can set this class for the view on the storyboard:
[image]

and as result you'll see:

[image]